# how to access the controls in child user control from parent aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I will like to know how I can access the textbox controls that I have in my WebUserControl from my Parent aspx page. I want that the user enters the data in texbox at the WebUserControl, then press the "Save" button which is in the parent page and the will be saved at SQL Server.

Comment: WebUserControl.FindControl(string id)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can expose the **Text** of **TextBox** of **WebUserControl** as public.

### WebUserControl.ascx.cs

```
public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string MyText
    {
        get { return MyTextBox.Text; }
        set { MyTextBox.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

### WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = WebUserControl1.MyText;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a much better idea than exposing the controls themselves. Let the user control track its own controls. Better still, have a `string` property in the user control, and use data binding to bind it to the text of the textbox.